# How to add icon and meta description on site so that it is visible when someone search on google in React JS

Tags: reactjs, web, meta-tags, favicon, google-search

I am using react js for website creation
Problem: I am not getting website icon and meta description while search on google.
but I am getting icon with title at the top when open website

[image]

Here is my code

```
`<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />


>! ḥere is my meta description tag 


    <meta name="description" content="I am not getting what i am writting here">


    <title>FutureIQRA</title>

here is my icon
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/src/Source/Assets/favicon_io/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/src/Source/Assets/favicon_io/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/src/Source/Assets/favicon_io/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/src/Source/Assets/favicon_io/site.webmanifest">


  </head>
 <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Caveat:wght@700&family=Dancing+Script:wght@500&family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <body 
  style="background-color: #2658e6" 
  >
    <div id="root"></div>
    
  
  </body>
  <script type="module" src="/src/index.jsx"></script>
    </html>`
```

I have tried adding meta tag and icon also but not working

Comment: Google's crawling and indexing of your new material may take some time. When waiting for search engine algorithm adjustments to take effect, patience is essential. 